# Trying to access fmin and fmax in Qt using math.h

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to use some basic C functions in Qt without any luck. I've tried both of the following:

`#include <math.h>`

`#include <cmath>`

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmin/), `fmin` and `fmax` should be in one of the above. But I cannot compile using these functions; i get the errors "identifier not found" for both of them.

Additionally, while I can open math.h in Qt, the fmin and fmax functions do not seem to be present in that file when I search for them. Is Qt using something else for these basic requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt doesn't mangle with the C++ standard headers. What is your environment, platform, compiler etc.?

In C++ it is easier to use `std::min()` and `std::max()` functions. They are templated, so you can just use them with two float arguments and obtain the same result as with `fmin`/`fmax`.
It is defined in the `algorithm` header.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::min/std::max or [qMin](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qMin)/[qMax](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qMax) (afaik, fmin and fmax c99 features)